# Don't know how to load 50 questions instead of 500

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Engine: Unity

I am using this game called QuizGame (it's free on [Github](https://github.com/WatchFindDo/QuizGameProject/tree/master/QuizGameProject))

The problem is, I have over 500 questions on my QuizGame (yes, it's important).
When I start the game, I have to pass every single one question.
Is there any other way to get only 50 questions from these 500 and start the game?
Then after the game, randomize another 50 from 500 and over and over again?

I think this is the problem:

```
    Question GetRandomQuestion()
    {
        var randomIndex = GetRandomQuestionIndex();
        currentQuestion = randomIndex;

        return Questions[currentQuestion];
    }
    int GetRandomQuestionIndex()
    {
        var random = 0;
        if (FinishedQuestions.Count < Questions.Length)
        {
            do
            {
                random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Questions.Length);
            } while (FinishedQuestions.Contains(10) || random == currentQuestion);
        }
        return random;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Call GetQuestions(50) to get random 50 questions
Question[] GetQuestions(int maxQuestions)
{
    System.Random random = new System.Random();

    // first, we shuffle your questions array
    // then, we take whatever amount you want
    return questions.OrderBy(_ => random.Next()).Take(maxQuestions).ToArray();
}
```